# Change save file format in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I read this question: [Can I split a spreadsheet into multiple files based on a column in Excel 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007/396954#396954?newreg=d3f6d5950fc44ee7bd67a15fce1e90bb)

I have a question regarding the "Save in same format as original workbook" that I hope you can help me with.

I'm using the macro with a CSV file but I want to have the final files like XLS.

How can the macro be changed to save in this format (different than original one)?

Comment: The macro is placed in the workbook.
The native format of this is xls (or xlsm)
that you use data from a csv file does not change the filetype of the workbook you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical sample:

```
Sub Sample_Cvs_To_Xlsx()
    ChDir "C:\TestFolder"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\WhatEver.csv"
    '
    ' perform processing
    '
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\TestFolder\WhatEver.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```