# Microsoft Excel 2013 - split spreadsheet to new workbooks and save to same folder as parent spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found some code done by mtone on March 5 2012 for "Can I split a spreadsheet into multiple files based on a column in Excel 2007?" at this link [Can I split a spreadsheet into multiple files based on a column in Excel 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007).
It works really well but I'd like it to save the workbooks into the same folder as the parent file.
Is this possible?
Thanks
Lynn

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of the code is:

```
 ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName, fileFormat
```

Change to

```
 ash.SaveAs sFilePath + sSectionName, fileFormat
```

Also, you can remove the earlier code that makes the split directory:

```
If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
End If
```