# <Excel> Split Main Spreadsheet Into Multiple Files Based On A Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My workbook has 1 main worksheet and 4 other worksheets.
Some of the cells in the main worksheet are referencing from the 4 other worksheets via formulas. I need to split the main worksheet into new workbooks based on a column, while making sure the 4 other worksheets are also copied over to the new workbooks.

[Can I split a spreadsheet into multiple files based on a column in Excel 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007) This code works beautifully, except that it doesn't copy over the 4 other worksheets into the new workbooks. Is there a way to do so by amending the code? Appreciate if anyone is able to help, thank you.

Comment: Use one more VBA code to copy multiple sheets to Wblook and call it at the end of existing VBA code.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have the code? Thank you.