# I am getting a run-time error 1004 when trying to split a spreadsheet into multiple files based on a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am using the macro from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007/396954#396954), which allows you to split up a file based on the values of a specified column. I adjusted it to add

```
Dim sMonthYear As String ' Month & Year of report

sMonthYear = Application.InputBox("Enter the Month and Year of the report", "Enter text", , , , , , 2)
```

where the user enters a string, and I changed the `SaveAs` so it looks like

```
ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName + "\" + sMonthYear + "\" + osh.Name, fileFormat
```

in order to create a file path that looks like: `\Split\Group 1\October 2019\Report.xlsx`. I also added `sMonthYear` to the commands on line 69, 87, and 114 to ensure the variable was passed to the new worksheet and saved.

However, when I run it, it gives me this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file ...\Split\Group 1\October 2019\CBAE2000'. There are several possible reasons:

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I remove the sMonthYear bit and the backslashes in the quotes, it works fine. When I click 'debug', it takes me to the ash.SaveAs line.

Comment: try it without spaces in the filepath

Comment: @AlexM Just tried that, it didn't work

Comment: Does that path actually exist beforehand?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad no, should it? when I run it with the original code, the \split folder doesn't exist but it creates it automatically

Comment: I always prefer creating the folder first. Try changing the `+` for `&` (`&` is exclusively for strings, `+` may produce unexpected results)